# Using existing User Entity with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I'm working with existing database and I want to use fields with FOSUser

I want to use the attribute "usuario" instead "username"

I've tried to login and I've got this error:

```
Unknown column 't0.username' in 'field list'
```

How can I do this work without rename my table field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have already figured this out, but just in case...

Add the annotation in your User.php entity class, $id variable:

```
* @ORM\Column(name="usuario", type="string", length=12, nullable=true)
```

and change the type, length and nullable to whatever values make sense for you.